# Call to undefined PHP function: tried everything i can think of

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

ive looked at everything that is typically the problem. maybe im looking to closely. can anyone tell what makes the "checkLocationExists" function undefined? i've checked brackets, ';'s, includes, open and closing php tags (closing one isn't shown here its at the end of the file.

```
<?php

require_once 'DBOperations.php';

class Functions{

private $db;

public function __construct() {
  $this -> db = new DBOperations();
}

public function searchPosts($rawLocation){
  $db = $this -> db;
  $locationArr = explode(",", $rawLocation);
  $formattedCity = $locationArr[0];
  $formattedState = $locationArr[1];
  echo 'String parameters for getLocationID are: 
'.$formattedCity.','.$formattedState.'.';
  if (checkLocationExists($formattedCity, $formattedState)){
      $locationID = $db -> getLocationID($formattedCity,
$formattedState);
      echo $locationID.'...is the locationId returned by "$db
>getLocationID()"';
      $response = $db -> getPostsByLocation($locationID);
      return json_encode($response);
  }else {
    $response['message'] = 'Location not in database, select one from
the AutoComplete drop down.';
    json_encode($response);
  }
}
public function checkLocationExists($city, $state) {
  $db = $this -> db;
  if ($db -> checkCity($city) && $db -> checkState($state) ) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When calling from within `class Functions`, try `$this->checkLocationExists()` instead of `checkLocationExists()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should modify the code to write `$this->checkLocationExists()` instead of `checkLocationExists()` because you are calling a class function.

and also please don't write `$db -> abcd` , instead write `$db->abcd` as it looks much more readable that way..
avoid that space before and after the arrow.

Comment: no issues.. you're welcome.. if this answer solved the issue then do upvote it and click on the checkmark